# unbalanced structure for comparison sentence

Tags: comparative-constructions

> It is not as cold in January as in December.

What kind of comparison it is?
Is it an unbalanced structure or not?

Comment: So you're asking about terminology?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the structure, it is grammatically correct, and can be considered parallel. The subject part *it is* is stated once for both January and December, while the preposition and month are stated twice, conserving the parallel structure.

Comment: The word "[conserving](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/conserve) the [structuralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuralism)" isn't quite right. Did you mean "maintain the parallel structure"?

Comment: My bad, yes, I didn't want to be repetitive, but it ended up being ambiguous.